# Run squid proxy service in a systemd enable centos 7 container

Tags: centos, systemd, docker, squid

I am unable to start squid service in a systemd enabled centos 7 container.

I am able to install the squid package.

this is what I got before starting the service :

```
[root@c65bf5111b85 /]# systemctl status squid
● squid.service - Squid caching proxy
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/squid.service; disabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: inactive (dead)
```

and then when I do the systemctl start squid this is what I got :

```
[root@c65bf5111b85 /]# systemctl status squid
● squid.service - Squid caching proxy
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/squid.service; disabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: inactive (dead)

Apr 28 23:46:23 c65bf5111b85 squid[269]: Squid Parent: will start 1 kids
Apr 28 23:46:23 c65bf5111b85 squid[269]: Squid Parent: (squid-1) process 273 started
Apr 28 23:46:23 c65bf5111b85 systemd[1]: Started Squid caching proxy.
Apr 28 23:46:23 c65bf5111b85 squid[276]: Squid Parent: will start 1 kids
Apr 28 23:46:23 c65bf5111b85 squid[276]: Squid Parent: (squid-1) process 280 started
Apr 28 23:46:23 c65bf5111b85 squid[269]: Squid Parent: (squid-1) process 273 exited with status 0
Apr 28 23:46:23 c65bf5111b85 squid[286]: Squid Parent: will start 1 kids
Apr 28 23:46:23 c65bf5111b85 squid[286]: Squid Parent: (squid-1) process 290 started
Apr 28 23:46:23 c65bf5111b85 squid[276]: Squid Parent: (squid-1) process 280 exited with status 0
Apr 28 23:46:23 c65bf5111b85 squid[283]: squid: No running copy
[root@c65bf5111b85 /]#
```

I am expecting the service to start as I was able to install and start httpd, nginx, mariadb services.

Comment: Do you have more information with `journalctl -xeu squid` ?